# Map a function over the array elements of a multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

Background:

- I have a function *hlpr_fun* that takes two arguments *a* and *b* and returns a list of float. Argument *a* is a 2D array of size 12x2 and *b* is an array of the same size consisting of random numbers. *hlpr_fun* calls another function *grad_calc* from within.

  ```
  from gradient_values import grad_calc 

  def hlpr_fun(a, b):   
      obj_func_val = []               
      epsilon_range = np.linspace(-1e-3, 1e-3, 51) 
      for eps in epsilon_range:
           perturbed_x  = a + (eps*b)
           obj_func_val.append(grad_calc(perturbed_x)) 

  return(obj_func_val)
  ```

The problem is like this:

- I require to call the function *hlpr_fun* for 100,000 times for 100,000 different values of both *a* and *b*. So, what I did is first created the arrays *a_array* and *b_array* of size 100000x12x2. I was trying np.vectorize, but got some errors.

Is there an efficient way to map the function *hlpr_fun* across each of the 12x2 array pairs of *a_array* and *b_array* propagating along axis = 0 ?

Comment: Depends on the implementation of `hlpr_fun`.

Comment: Can you show example input and output?

Comment: can you also show `hlpr_fun', or is it very long?

Comment: Try modifying hlpr_fun to take r dimensional array with the default being 1 by 12 by 2 such that you can change the first dimension. Most important, provide an example so people can give specific help. Using map on arrays is not the numpy way. Broadcasting is.

Comment: 'hlpr-fun' is shown now.

Comment: But it's dependent on `grad_calc`, which would also need to be vectorized.  I assume that's also your own work?

Comment: ok, than  I am considering to vectorize 'grad_calc'. It was unjustifiable, I was hoping for some magic. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: You might be able to do some `numba` magic on it to vectorize, but without seeing the code we can't begin to tell you how.

Comment: If you can vectorize `grad_calc` you can get rid of the inner for loop. Then you might be able to vectorize `hlpr_fun` aswell to avoid looping for every possible value of `a` and `b`.

Comment: grad_calc is already very heavily vectorized but looks like I will have to give it one shot tonight to take it to another level of vectorization.